# Expo icon shown before splash screen on android

Tags: expo, splash-screen

We're working on an app that works great but on iOS but on Android when the user opens the app the icon from the app is shown momentary before the splash screen is shown. This doesn't happen on IOS. I can't figure out if I'm doing something wrong or if it's a bug in expo.

First the foregroundImage for android is shown and THEN the splash screen instead of the splash screen only.

Here is the page where the splash screen is loaded:

```
import React, { useCallback, Dispatch, SetStateAction, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
import * as Sentry from 'sentry-expo';

import {Platform} from 'react-native'

import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

import {NavigationContainer,DefaultTheme} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

  
import Home from './src/screens/loggedin/Home'
import Login from './src/screens/notloggedin/Login'

   
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const appTheme = {
    ...DefaultTheme,
    colors: {
        ...DefaultTheme.colors,
        primary: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
        card: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
        background: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'
    }
};

Platform.OS == "ios" && SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

function App({navigation}:any){


  const [appIsReady, setAppIsReady] = useState(false);
  const [user,setUser] = useState<string|null>(null)
  const [hasVisitedAppBefore,setHasVisitedAppBefore] : [string,any] = useState("false")

  // is signed in
  let isSignedin = user==null||user=="" ? false : true

  
  useEffect(() => {
 

    async function prepare() {

      // set user if exist
      if (await AsyncStorage.getItem('user')!=null){
        let userData : any = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user')
        setUser(JSON.parse(userData).sub)
      }

      try {
        setHasVisitedAppBefore(await AsyncStorage.getItem("hasVisited"))

        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));

      } catch (e) {
        console.warn(e);
      } finally {
        setAppIsReady(true);
      }
    }

    prepare();
  }, []);




  if (!appIsReady){
    return
  } else {
    SplashScreen.hideAsync();
  }

  return (
    <NavigationContainer theme={appTheme}>

        {!isSignedin ? 
        <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{gestureEnabled: false}}>
          {(hasVisitedAppBefore=="false"||hasVisitedAppBefore==null) && <Stack.Screen name="Initial" component={Initial} options={{title: 'App', headerShown:false}} />}
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Login} options={{title: 'App', headerShown:false}} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
        :
        /** loggedin */
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={"Home"} screenOptions={{gestureEnabled: false}}>
        
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{title: 'App', headerShown:false}} />
         
        </Stack.Navigator>
        }
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is the app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "app",
    "slug": "app",
    "version": "2.1.3",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ],
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/app_icon.png", 
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash_icon.png", <-- this is the icon that loads as second image (the only image that SHOULD load)
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSCameraUsageDescription": "XXX",
        "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription": "XXX."
      },
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.somepackage.app"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/android_app_icon.png", <-- this is the app icon that loads first when the app is opened

        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "permissions": [
        "android.permission.CAMERA",
        "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
        "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
        "android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"
      ],
      "package": "com.somepackage.app",      
      "config": {
        "googleMaps": {
          "apiKey": "XXX"
        }
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-barcode-scanner",
        {
          "cameraPermission": "XXX"
        }
      ],
      [
        "expo-location",
        {
          "locationAlwaysAndWhenInUsePermission": "XXX"
        }
      ],
      "sentry-expo"
    ],
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "XXX"
      }
    },
    "owner": "XXX",
    "runtimeVersion": {
      "policy": "appVersion"
    },
    "updates": {
      "url": "XXX"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a video of the error:

[Link to video](http://website-estands.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/406260232_6372972472806684_5031472334675276001_n.mp4)

package.json relevant info:

```
>    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",

>     "expo": "^49.0.0",
```

Comment: Maybe try the ["native" resize mode](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/main/packages/expo-splash-screen/README.md#native-resize-mode), although it is [not perfect](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/main/packages/expo-splash-screen/README.md#native-mode-pushes-splash-image-up-a-little-bit)

Answer (score 0):

Have you read up on the definition of an `adaptiveIcon` for Android?  It is linked to from [this page in the Expo docs](https://docs.expo.dev/develop/user-interface/app-icons/#android).  If you follow the docs over to the Android page, I see [this description of the Android splash screen](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen#elements) which I assume is being displayed before the Expo splash screen gets up and running?

Comment: Yes. Only the splash screen should be shown. It works fine on all IOS devices but not on all android. It doesn't work correctly on samsung phones (this is my latest discovery in the bugging) It also works fine in the emulator.

Comment: My assumption is that the default Android splash screen is being rendered while your app is loading, starting up the JS engine, interpreting the RN/Expo code, and eventually realizing it needs to put up the Expo splash screen.  I could be wrong about that...but I can't figure out why else you'd be seeing your default icon as a splash screen before your Expo splash screen.  iOS app startup almost certainly is unlike an Android app startup.